# Regarding "Insert query error" in wordpress

Tags: mysql, errors

I am getting "Insert query error" in my WordPress eCommerce website when I click on the place order button. My error is:

> Insert query error - Table 'i1503672_wp6.wp_wa_product_orders' doesn't exist

Query:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wp_wa_product_orders`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanking you.

Comment: To state the obvious, that is the correct table name?